# python format is failing when trying to format and html string

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why pythons' `format`

```
OUTPUT_HTML_PATH = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'formats',
    'html')
with open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_HTML_PATH, 'index.html'), 'r') as f:
    OUTPUT_HTML_PAGE = f.read()

OUTPUT_HTML_PAGE.format(feedback_json=json.dumps(
            feedback, indent=2, sort_keys=True),
            resources_path=args.resources_path)
```

The `format` succeeded in case of the old `index.html`.

Once I've tried to change the `index.html` with adding a script tag like so:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadScript(url, callback){
        a=1
    }
</script>
```

I'm getting

```
KeyError: '\n            a=1\n        '
```

My function was simplified to reduce complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python you are using this string:

```
"""<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadScript(url, callback){
        a=1
    }
  </script>"""
```

If you check the `format` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), you will see that it uses '{}' as the place holder where the input data will be placed. So in your string you have `a=1` inside that place holder hence python doesn't know what to do with it.

In order to solve this, you woul have to add double `"{{}}"` to scape them in the string so python doesn't recognize them as a formatting token:

```
"""<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadScript(url, callback){{
        a=1
    }}
  </script>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *escape* any `{` or `}` characters that are not part of a formatting slot; do so by doubling them:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadScript(url, callback){{
        a=1
    }}
  </script>
```

You may want to look at specialised templating libraries however, such as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), or [any of the other widely used engines](https://www.fullstackpython.com/template-engines.html); these let you use conditionals and other programming constructs too, not just simply interpolate values into fixed slots.